# Parsec-Haskell, formatting parse errors

Tags: haskell, parsec, arithmetic-expressions, mathematical-expressions

I am developing a simple calculator that takes one line of input, parses it using parsec and then processes it.

I want to make the parsec parse-error messages smaller. They include position info which is not necessary for a one line input. I've tried using `<?>` but it doesn't quite do what I want.

Trying to extract the cause of parse error didn't yield good results.

Some way to specify errors for unmatched parentheses, or just a `syntax error` message would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get at the error messages and source position of an error using the `errorMessages`, `messageString`, `errorPos` and `sourceColumn` functions from `Text.Parsec.Error`.

Here is an example taken from [this blog post](http://www.mega-nerd.com/erikd/Blog/CodeHacking/Haskell/parsec_expression_parsing.html). It demonstrates the use of `<?>` and using the above mentioned functions to customize error processing:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Expr
import Text.Parsec.Error

expr :: Parser Integer
expr = buildExpressionParser table factor <?> "expression"

table :: [[ Operator Char st Integer ]]
table = [
    [ op "*" (*) AssocLeft, op "/" div AssocLeft ],
    [ op "+" (+) AssocLeft, op "-" (-) AssocLeft ]
    ]
  where
    op s f assoc = Infix (do { string s ; return f }) assoc

factor = do { char '(' ; x <- expr ; char ')' ; return x }
   <|> number
   <?> "simple expression"

number :: Parser Integer
number = do { ds <- many1 digit; return (read ds) } <?> "number"

doit str =
  case parse expr "blah" str of
    Left e -> do let msgs = filter (not.null) $ map messageString (errorMessages e)
                 let col = sourceColumn (errorPos e)
                 putStrLn $ "error at column " ++ show col ++ ": " ++ show msgs
    Right x -> putStrLn $ "ok - got: " ++ show x

main = do
  doit "3+5"
  doit "5-"
  doit "("
```

Comment: That's a good idea. When I used `map messageString` it gave strange results. I never thought about manually providing custom error messages using `<?>` and then trying to extract the errors. Thanks.